# postgresql function rturned type text does not match expected type character varying

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, select

So I have this function which gives me the gender and age the facility, the total members, the general members, the course members, and the club members.
The select part works as expected but when I try to put in the function it returns this error:
`ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.`

When I use select separately it works and it returns the column gender_age_category as expected such as this f>17.

Is 'f>17' this string not considered a varchar(255)? I don't understand why the function does not work.

Here the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gender_age_log_counts(start_date character varying(255), end_date character varying(255))
RETURNS TABLE (
            gender_age_category varchar(255), 
            facility_id varchar(255),
            total bigint,
            general bigint,
            course bigint,
            club bigint
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) >= 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f>17'
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) >= 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm>17'
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) < 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f<18'
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) < 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm<18' 
        END AS gender_age_category,
        l.facility_id,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN l.card_id = m.card_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS total,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN l.log_type = 'general' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS general,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN l.log_type = 'course' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS course,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN l.log_type = 'club' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS club 
    FROM members m  
    LEFT JOIN
        logs l ON m.card_id = l.card_id
    WHERE l."login" >= start_date::date AND l."login" <= end_date::date 
    GROUP BY gender_age_category, l.facility_id
    ORDER BY gender_age_category ASC;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Aside - using `character varying(255)` and `varchar(255)` is not the best practice in PostgreSQL. Try to replace them with `text`.

Comment: Try `gender_age_category::varchar` and `facility_id::varchar`. FYI, in Postgres `varchar` does not have to have a length qualifier, so you can do `gender_age_category varchar`.

Comment: `start_date character varying(255)` will result in errors since you can't cast `August the 25th 2016` to a date: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "August the 25th 2016"`. When you need a date as input, you should demand a date as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the type of that column using this pg_typeof like in this example

```
SELECT pg_typeof(column_name) FROM table_name LIMIT 1;
```

it was type TEXT and not varchar